# Создание связанных таблиц в Mysql

Tags: mysql, relation

Добрый день.
Есть следующих код для создани таблиц в бд и их связывание, но когда импортирую этот скрипт выходят ошибки что не так, подскажите пожалуйста:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
    `id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_code` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `country_name` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
    `id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `city_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `latitude` DOUBLE(24,18) NOT NULL,
    `longitude` DOUBLE(24,18) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `country_id` (`country_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hotels` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `city_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `hotel_name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    `stars` FLOAT(2,1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `latitude` DOUBLE(24,18) NOT NULL,
    `longitude` DOUBLE(24,18) NOT NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `photo` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `hightlights` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `description` TEXT(4000) NOT NULL,
    `rooms` SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `url` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `city_id` (`city_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partners` (
    `id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `partner_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partners_hotels` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `hotel_id` MEDIUMINT(7) NOT NULL,
    `partner_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `hotel_id` (`hotel_id`),
     KEY `partner_id` (`partner_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prices` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `hotel_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `partner_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `low` FLOAT(8, 2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `hight` FLOAT(8, 2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `currency` VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `hotel_id` (`hotel_id`),
     KEY `partner_id` (`partner_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `cities`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cities_countries` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `hotels`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_hotels_cities` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `partners_hotels`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_partners_hotels_partners` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partners` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `partners_hotels`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_partners_hotels_hotels` FOREIGN KEY (`hotel_id`) REFERENCES `hotels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `prices`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_prices_hotels` FOREIGN KEY (`hotel_id`) REFERENCES `hotels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `prices`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_prices_partners` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partners_hotels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `countries` ADD INDEX `country_code` (`country_code`);
ALTER TABLE `cities` ADD INDEX `city_name` (`city_name`);
ALTER TABLE `hotels` ADD INDEX `hotel_name` (`hotel_name`);
```

И есть еще вопрос правильно ли созданы связи, в последующем нужно будет извлекать все данные одной строкой с использованием `JOIN's`

Ошибка:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `partners_hotels`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_partners_hotels_hotels` FOREIGN KEY (`hotel_id`) REFERENCES `hotels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

`#1005 - Can't create table`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для создания внешнего ключа MySQL необходимо совпадение сигнатур полей, другими словами, типы этих двух полей должны совпадать (за тем исключением, что внешний ключ может быть NULL, в то время как на референс-поле может быть запрет на NULL).

У вас `partners_hotels.hotel_id` имеет тип `MEDIUMINT(7) NOT NULL`, в то время как `hotels.id` имеет тип `MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`. Несовпадение этих типов дает MySQL повод предполагать, что нельзя обеспечить целостность данных, поэтому MySQL отказывается выполнить операцию.

Comment: `@Etki` Спасибо большое.